# What does the little yellow minus mean on the psn?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

When on the PlayStation network sometimes I find that I or my friends have a yellow minus instead of a blue circle or a red "X". I thought this might mean the power is off but I find that I have a minus sometimes so what in the world does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PSVita manual](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/psvita/friends/profile.html), it means "Not available".

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any authoritative source on when someone is considered "Not available", but according to [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/21sq6d/does_anybody_know_what_the_orange_status_is_next/) you get this status when:

- You've manually set it on PS3.
- Your PS Vita is in standby.

Comment: what does "standby" mean?

Comment: @CiurkitboyN, your PS Vita is in standby when its screen is turned off, but the device is still running. When in standby, you can instantly turn your Vita back on, and resume your game even if you didn't save.

Comment: ok that makes sense